# upload image array on server side

Tags: android

I am trying to add any number of images user chose from gallery and add them once on server side. But only one image is added. My image array upload condition is in temp==1.

Here is my code :

```
private String uploadFile() {
            String responseString = null;

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

            try {
                AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                        new ProgressListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void transferred(long num) {
                                publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                            }
                        });
                if(temp==1)
                {
                for (int i = 0; i < filePatharr.length; i++) {
                    File sourceFile = new File(filePatharr[i]);
                    entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));
                }
                }
                if(temp==0)
                {
                File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

                // Adding file data to http body
                entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));
                }
                /*
                 * // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server
                 * entity.addPart("website", new
                 * StringBody("www.androidhive.info")); entity.addPart("email",
                 * new StringBody("abc@gmail.com"));
                 */

                totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
                httppost.setEntity(entity);

                // Making server call
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    // Server response
                    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                } else {
                    responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                            + statusCode;
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            }

            return responseString;

        }
```

filePatharr is my string array in which i get images path. Is there problem at my end or backend(PHP side). Can anyone help me plz

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < filePatharr.length; i++) {
    File sourceFile = new File(filePatharr[i]);
    entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));
}
```

You always overwrite HTTP POST *image* parameter, thus only the last image will be uploaded (or the first, I don't know how apache's library exactly work).

For instance you can use *"image" + i* as post param, and additionally you can pass a *"numOfImages"* post parameter to know how many images were uploaded.

Comment: if i use "image"+i , then the same parameters must be defines at php end. but i dont know in advance how many images will be selected from gallery

Comment: That's why you add a post parameter which contains the number of the images, thus you will know how many images were uploaded. And you can process them in a simple for loop on the server side.